# Wordpress Two themes with same name

Tags: php, css, wordpress, svn, themes

I would like to develop a Wordpress theme, using a main development trunk for minor changes and a branch for the next page release. So I checked out my SVN trunk directory in `wp-content/themes/themename-trunk` and my current branch in `wp-content/themes/themename-branch`.

The theme is then selected by a user-depending plugin.

Now, Wordpress uses a CSS comment for displaying the theme name. Obviously, WP does not use the directory name for distinguishing between themes internally. I definitely do not want to change the line containing the name in the style.css beacause otherwise this will create a mess in my SVN files and will make easy switching impossible.

Do you have another strategy for combining WP theme development with a multi-programmer SVN environment without maintainig a second WP installation?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use custom [`svn:keywords`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) with Subversion 1.8 client?

E.g. set `$themename$` keyword in your theme's CSS for theme name and specify the keyword on CSS file in *"wp-content/themes/themename-trunk"* and in *"wp-content/themes/themename-branch"* as "themename-trunk" and "themename-branch" accordingly. The keyword is going to be expanded like `$themename: themename-branch $` in the CSS file. You can change the keyword to the real name of the theme later.

PS I may be missing some prettier and more obvious solution here (e.g. using [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html)) but thought of keywords as the possible solutuion.